# Submit form from button behavior

Tags: jquery

I'd like to submit a form from button.

HTML

```
<form id="form-search" action="index.php" method="post">
  <select id="s1" name="s1" size="1">
    <option value=""></option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="btn_src" />
  <input type="button" value="RESET" id="btn_reset" />    
</form>
```

I tried in this way but it does not work

```
$('#btn_reset' ).click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#form-search').submit();
});
```

So I tried it this way (trigger click) and it works fine, but I noticed that if my button is disabled I have to click 2 times before the form is executed.
I also tried to re-enable the button before but with no success.

```
$('select#s1').change(function()
{
   var s1 = $('select#s1 option:selected').prop('value');

   if(s1 == 4)
   {
       $('#btn_src').prop('disabled', true);
   }
});

$('#btn_reset' ).click(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
   //$('#form-search').submit(); <-- not work
   $('#btn_src').prop('disabled', false);
   $('#btn_src').trigger('click');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ap9d/)

how can I fix it? then why is this behavior? thanks

UPDATE - SOLVED !

Adding timeout after re-enable the submit button I fix the problem.

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#btn_src').trigger('click'); }, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to me you need to make it a "button" rather than an "input" ...

```
<button id="btn_reset">RESET</button>
```

That hopefully should do it ...

Apols ... wrong cut and paste last time... okay try this ...

```
$('select#s1').change(function()
{
var s1 = $('select#s1 option:selected').prop('value');

if(s1 === "4")
{
    $('#btn_src').prop('disabled', true);
} else {
    $('#btn_src').prop('disabled', false);
}

});

 $('#btn_reset' ).click(function(e)
 {
e.preventDefault();

    $('#form-search').submit(); // not work
    $('#btn_src').prop('disabled', false);
$('#btn_src').trigger('click');
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes. I have to click twice if the submit button is disabled

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what is the difference between your code and my..